# How to enable azure windows vm extension for IaaSDiagnostics with terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

Is there any example of enabling IaaSDiagnostics for azure windows vm's via terraform?

I get the following error when trying to deploy my plan, looking in the portal it half kinda deploys but it isn't happy and terraform will keep trying to re-deploy.

```
Error: Code="VMExtensionProvisioningError" Message="VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'IaaSDiagnostics'. Error message: \"Exception when parsing configuration: Error: The element 'PublicConfig' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'WadCfg, StorageAccount, LocalResourceDirectory, StorageType, WadCfgBlob' in namespace '
```

I have the following terraform resource:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "diag" {
  name                 = "IaaSDiagnostics"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics"
  type                 = "IaaSDiagnostics"
  type_handler_version = "1.5"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "xmlCfg": "${base64encode(file(local.diagConfigFile))}",
        "storageAccount": "${azurerm_storage_account.vm.name}"
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "storageAccountName": "${azurerm_storage_account.vm.name}",
        "storageAccountKey":  "${azurerm_storage_account.vm.primary_access_key}}",
        "storageAccountEndPoint":  "${azurerm_storage_account.vm.primary_blob_endpoint}}"
    }
SETTINGS

}
```

And my config file have this json:

```
{
  "StorageAccount": "$$StorageName",
  "WadCfg": {
    "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
      "overallQuotaInMB": 5120,
      "Metrics": {
        "resourceId": "$$resourceId",
        "MetricAggregation": [
          {
            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1H"
          },
          {
            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
          }
        ]
      },
      "DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs": {
        "scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter": "Error",
        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
      },
      "PerformanceCounters": {
        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
        "PerformanceCounterConfiguration": [
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Processor Information(_Total)% Processor Time",
            "unit": "Percent",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Processor Information(_Total)% Privileged Time",
            "unit": "Percent",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Processor Information(_Total)% User Time",
            "unit": "Percent",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Processor Information(_Total)Processor Frequency",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "SystemProcesses",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Process(_Total)Thread Count",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Process(_Total)Handle Count",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "SystemSystem Up Time",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "SystemContext Switches/sec",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "SystemProcessor Queue Length",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Memory% Committed Bytes In Use",
            "unit": "Percent",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "MemoryAvailable Bytes",
            "unit": "Bytes",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "MemoryCommitted Bytes",
            "unit": "Bytes",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "MemoryCache Bytes",
            "unit": "Bytes",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "MemoryPool Paged Bytes",
            "unit": "Bytes",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "MemoryPool Nonpaged Bytes",
            "unit": "Bytes",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "MemoryPages/sec",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "MemoryPage Faults/sec",
            "unit": "CountPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Process(_Total)Working Set",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Process(_Total)Working Set - Private",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)% Disk Time",
            "unit": "Percent",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)% Disk Read Time",
            "unit": "Percent",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)% Disk Write Time",
            "unit": "Percent",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)% Idle Time",
            "unit": "Percent",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Disk Bytes/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Disk Read Bytes/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Disk Write Bytes/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Disk Transfers/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Disk Reads/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Disk Writes/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Avg. Disk sec/Transfer",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Avg. Disk sec/Read",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Avg. Disk sec/Write",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Avg. Disk Queue Length",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Avg. Disk Read Queue Length",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Avg. Disk Write Queue Length",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)% Free Space",
            "unit": "Percent",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "LogicalDisk(_Total)Free Megabytes",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Network Interface()Bytes Total/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Network Interface()Bytes Sent/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Network Interface()Bytes Received/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Network Interface()Packets/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Network Interface()Packets Sent/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Network Interface()Packets Received/sec",
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Network Interface()Packets Outbound Errors",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          },
          {
            "counterSpecifier": "Network Interface()Packets Received Errors",
            "unit": "Count",
            "sampleRate": "PT60S"
          }
        ]
      },
      "WindowsEventLog": {
        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M",
        "DataSource": [
          {
            "name": "Application![System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]"
          },
          {
            "name": "System![System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]"
          },
          {
            "name": "Security!*[System[(band(Keywords,4503599627370496))]]"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Directories": {
        "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
      },
      "sinks": "applicationInsights"
    },
    "SinksConfig": {
      "Sink": [
        {
          "name": "applicationInsights",
          "ApplicationInsights": "$$AppInstKey"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I found this on another page (https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2943) and might be the root of my problem, but I can't find any other examples of this config elsewhere, is it possible to somehow extract it from a VM which already been enabled?

EDIT----

I found the install logs on the VM (`C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.18.0.5`) so I compared it between the terraform install and doing it through the portal.

When doing it via terraform the json is wrapped in some xml tags (which I guess explains the error):

```
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [4/12/2021 6:58:54 PM] WadCfg is provided in initial configuration. Using that to initialize Diagnostics.
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [4/12/2021 6:58:54 PM] <PublicConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">{
  "WadCfg": {
    "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
      "overallQuotaInMB": 5120,
```

Where as the portal install has this:

```
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [4/12/2021 6:48:44 PM] WadCfg is provided in initial configuration. Using that to initialize Diagnostics.
DiagnosticsPlugin.exe Information: 0 : [4/12/2021 6:48:44 PM] { "WadCfg": {
  "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
    "overallQuotaInMB": 5120,
```

Any ideas how to stop terraform adding the XML?

Answer (score 1):

I found two example XML configs which means I can use these instead of the JSON which then install correctly:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/diagnostics-extension-schema-windows#xml
and a full terraform example:
https://gist.github.com/tombuildsstuff/92191dd7de42310b2874884777e87fbe